# PHP/laravel: Assign input name to input value

Tags: php, json, laravel, input

I have a simple structure:

```
       @for ($i = 1; $i <= $page_num; $i++) // $page_num = 37;
            <div class="divTableRow">
                <div class="divTableCell">{{$i}}</div>
                <input name="{{$i}}" value="{{$i}}" type="number"/>
            </div>
       @endfor
```

This is a controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $bodyContent = $request->getContent();
    $obj = json_encode($bodyContent);
    dd($obj); // here I want to see, what I get
}
```

So I get such a thing:

`"_token=VcSFPaYfdte9zb7Xa6c42vsxilwFnZ2hWLOxV&1=1&2=2&3=3&4=4&5=5&6=6&7=7&8=8&9=9&10=10&11=11&12=12&13=13&14=14&15=15&16=16&17=17&18=18&19=19&20=20&21=21&22=22&23=23&24=24&25=25&26=26&27=27&28=28&29=29&30=30&31=31&32=32&33=33&34=34&35=35&36=36&37=37 ◀"`

Is it possible to transform it to json format after all?:

```
{
  "1" : "1",
  "2" : "2",
  "3" : "3",
  "4" : "4",
   .. : ..,
   .
   .
  "37" : "37"
}
```

If yes, could someone point me the way to solve this issue?
Later have to save this formated output to the file `*.json`, but for now it is not important.
Searched for the Hints, but nothing helps, I get endless errors

Comment: use ```$request->query()``` to get the query string from request

Comment: didn't help, I get empty array `[ ]`

Comment: are you submitting form via post or get ? if its post then use request->all()

Comment: Thanks for your attention to this topic! Upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `$request->all();` which return an array of all the input fields, then encoding that to json should give you your desired output.

So:

```
$obj = json_encode($request->all());
```

should be what you are looking for. And in order to exclude the token you can use:

```
$obj = json_encode($request->except('_token'));
```

Comment: Yeap, that helped. Indeed simple as that... )) thank you! Marked your answer.